# Assigning output of grep to a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to assign the output of a grep command to a variable in a bash script and the variable comes up empty. When I run the following:

```
el_value=$(grep '<$2>.*<$2>' $1 | sed -e 's/^.*<$2/<$2/' | cut -f2 -d'>'| cut -f1 -d':')
echo "DEBUG: The value of el_value is '$el_value'"
```

The output is:

```
DEBUG: The value of el_value is ''
```

If I run the grep command outside of the script (and substitute the variables for real values) I get the output I'm expecting.

---

Here is a snippet of script. Use this script and add the values listed above.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
echo 1>&2 'This script replaces xml element’s value with the one provided as a command parameter \n\n\tUsage: $0 <xml filename> <element name> <new value>'
exit 127
fi

el_value=`grep "<$2>.*<$2>" $1 | sed -e "s/^.*<$2/<$2/" | cut -f2 -d'>'| cut -f1 -d':'`
echo "DEBUG: The value of el_value is '$el_value'"
```

Comment: Something happened when I posted the command. It's actually:

Comment: el_value=$(grep '<$2>.*<$2>' $1 | sed -e 's/^.*<$2/<$2/' | cut -f2 -d'>'| cut -f1 -d':')

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
el_value=$(sed -n "s/.*<$2>\([^:<]*\).*/\1/p" < "$1")
```

In your code the problems were:

- single quotes around `$2` which meant it wasn't expanded
- missing `/` to search for the closing tag in the `grep` command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a quote issue. Inside your `grep` & `sed` argument, `$1` and `$2` are not parsed because of your simple quotes (`'`).
Try this one :

```
el_value=$(grep "<$2>.*<$2>" $1 | sed -e "s/^.*<$2/<$2/" | cut -f2 -d'>'| cut -f1 -d':')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still get the same results.

Comment: Please post some content for testing.

Comment: Create a file called file.xml. Add this line to the file: <p4Port>server1:1986</p4Port>. Then pass in the values file.xml server1 server2

Comment: I think you want to do this : `el_value=$(grep "<$2>.*</$2>" $1 | sed -e "s/^.*<$2/<$2/" | cut -f2 -d'>'| cut -f1 -d':')`. And call it with `file.xml p4Port server1`. Remember that xml langage is not a regular langage, so you might find case wich your sed exp will not work. Use a xml parser and a script langage like python/ruby/perl/other